# Is it correct this pronoun to replace a subject?

Tags: pronouns, subjects

> Taking into consideration the skills of Hassim in these courses, I am sure she made the right decision in choosing the master’s in agriculture. Furthermore, this master is crucial for enhancing his capacity to research and develop **projects** related to food production, **which are** required **to assist** the urgent demand of food for zones with scarcity.

1. Is it clear that **which are** is referring to **projects** in this sentence?
2. Is it correct to say ....**to assist** the urgent demand? I don't want to use **to supply** because I used it previously.

Comment: _She_ or _his_? How many people are we talking about here?

Comment: help me the demand, not assist

Comment: help meet the demand?

Comment: A little sidenote, the last part of ..."urgent demand of food for..." should be for , not of... otherwise it's the food that has demands, and thats just weird :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several idiomatic and stylistic errors in what you have proposed, but none that will prevent comprehension. Your “which are” is fine; no problem there. Your use of “assist” does not mean what you want it to mean, but people will figure out what you intend. What you should say is “assist in meeting the demand” rather than “assist the demand.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is clear that "which are" refers to "projects", because that's the only plural noun that comes before it. "This master" (which should be "this master's") is singular, while "his capacity" and "food production" are uncountable, and "are" is only used for countable plurals.

No, "urgent demand" could not be "assisted". I would suggest using the word "address" instead:

> to **address** the urgent demand

if you don't want to spell out exactly what actions they are taking that provide assistance.